# Google map Loading Error -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ga' of undefined at common.js:143

Tags: google-maps

Getting the error
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ga' of undefined at common.js:143** while loading google maps since today. 
Using Version: 3.27
Api call - [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=CLIENT_ID&v=3.27&libraries=geometry,places,drawing&callback=gMapsCallback](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=&v=3.27&libraries=geometry,places,drawing&callback=gMapsCallback)

The map had been working fine,no other changes were made in the code. Debugging a bit could see a reference of "this" value getting changed in the common.js function of the google maps for some tile load calls.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As the frozen version is now 3.29, It is plausible to assume that a new version came into force and, as a result the version you are now running (3.27) throws an error. See all the [relative info here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the frozen version is now 3.29, It is plausible to assume that a new version came into force and, as a result the version you are now running (3.27) throws an error. See all the [relative info here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)

You just have to request the frozen version with the following bootstrap:

```
<script async defer
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.29 
 &key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

Comment: Have tried that as well but still getting errors. But with different line numbers. Have tried degrading/ upper versions as well.

Comment: Ok the error you are getting **common js 143** is not coming from your source code but from an external application; are you able to send a self-contained snippet to reproduce the issue?

Comment: yes its comming from external source. Had a talk with google team, the issue was because of the new release. when got a Rolled back version as a result and it works fine. The issue is due to getting a release version(30) even when had been requesting 27 . Thanks